# Automatically save a buffer when using bdelete command in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to automatically write a buffer on removing it from the list of open buffers with the `bd` the same way I use `x` when I only have one open buffer.

I have set the `set hidden` option of course.
I have tried to put `autocmd BufDelete * w` (or `... update` or `...w!`) but alas it does not work.

I have also tried to `set autowrite`  in my .vimrc although it does more than what I would like but it did not work either :
No matter what vim complains that the changes have not been written.

I did read the manual `:h autowrite/hidden/autocmd-events` and did not find my answer.
How do I do it or what am I missing ? Is there something wrong with my buffer workflow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do but you do it wrong for sure. `:bd` is not the right tool for closing random buffers; use `:x` and such instead.

Comment: @Matt `:x` won't save and dump the buffer so ...

Comment: It is not allowed to save inactive buffers except `wall` and such. Again, what you do is a misuse. Your question is invalid and/or unclear.

Comment: It is not inactive. I am in a buffer. I have many others open. I am done editing this buffer and don't need it anymore in my buffer list. So I want to remove it. I just want it to be saved before. I am tired of being treated like a mad man for wanting some basic feature. In any other editor you would just close a tab and there would be a option for autowriting on close. What's possibly wrong with that ? If you think it's wrong, tell me why. But it is not unclear at all.

Comment: "Listed" is a **buffer-local option**. It only influences if a buffer is shown by `:ls` or not. It is set and reset like any other option.

Comment: Kind of unrelated but I `set confirm` and if your buffer was not saved when you `:bd`'ed , you just have to press`y`(es)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the only way:

```
function! CarefullyDelCurrentBuf()
    update
    bdelete!
endfunction

command! BD call CarefullyDelCurrentBuf()
```

Now use `:BD` instead of `:bd`.

Comment: If it's the only way : What about `command BD w | bd` ?